# Getting value of internal div when outside div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following: A bunch of button div's which each have unique info

```
<div class="button">
  <div id="first">
      Johny
  </div> 
  <div id="second">
      Dog
  </div>
  <div id="third">
      Pasta
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div id="first">
      Bob
  </div> 
  <div id="second">
      Cat
  </div>
  <div id="third">
      Noodles
  </div>
</div>
   .
   . 
   .
```

I'm trying to make it so that when one of these buttons is clicked, i can check the values of the inner divs.

For instance

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
     // Check to see if the text of the 'first' div is 
     // johnny or bob or something else
});
```

Comment: `$(this).children()` will gives you all the children for the current div. From this you can get the text by iterating over that array

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot use same id for multiple elements in a page.So,Instead use class for that.Ex:

```
<div class="button">
  <div class="first">
      Johny
  </div> 
  <div class="second">
      Dog
  </div>
  <div class="third">
      Pasta
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="first">
      Bob
  </div> 
  <div class="second">
      Cat
  </div>
  <div class="third">
      Noodles
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in the javascript:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
     var first=this.getElementsByClassName("first")[0];//gets first element of this button

var second=this.getElementsByClassName("second")[0];

var third=this.getElementsByClassName("third")[0];

//Now you do what ever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).children(":first").text()` to get fist div's text

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
       if ($(this).find("#first").html().trim() == "Johny") {
           console.log("The first div is Johny");
       } else if ($(this).find("#first").html().trim() == "Bob") {
           console.log("The first div is Bob");
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about giving each div its own click handler? (you will need unique ids for this to work properly)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bchildren = $('.button').children();
    $(bchildren).click(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
    }  
</script>
```